# How can i fix SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked error while trying to access a SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve some data from a Sqlite database. But when I try to retrieve data using the method getTaskSent, I get the following errors. Can anyone suggest me a solution for the following errors?

```
  E/AndroidRuntime(23159):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
```

Here is my database code:

```
public class Databasehandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final String LOGCAT = null;

public Databasehandler(Context applicationcontext) {
    super(applicationcontext,"androidsqlite.db", null, 4);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Log.d(LOGCAT,"Database Created");

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String query,query1,query2; 
    query = "CREATE TABLE userlogin ( phoneId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,username TEXT,userid INTEGER,contacts TEXT UNIQUE)";
 query1 = "CREATE TABLE task ( TaskId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,heading TEXT,desc TEXT,d1 TEXT,d2 TEXT,t1 TEXT,t2 TEXT,receiver TEXT,sender TEXT)";
 query2 = "CREATE TABLE me ( fbId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,fbname TEXT,fbuserid INTEGER,fbpic BLOB,ph TEXT,email TEXT)"; 
 db.execSQL(query1);
    db.execSQL(query);
    db.execSQL(query2);

}
 public void inserttask(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
    values2.put("heading", queryValues.get("heading"));
    values2.put("desc", queryValues.get("desc"));
    values2.put("d1", queryValues.get("d1"));
    values2.put("d2", queryValues.get("d2"));
    values2.put("t1", queryValues.get("t1"));
    values2.put("t2", queryValues.get("t2"));
    values2.put("sender", queryValues.get("sender"));
    values2.put("receiver", queryValues.get("receiver"));

    database.insert("task", null, values2);
    database.close();
}
  public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getTaskSent() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
    wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM task";

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            //map.put("userid", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("heading", cursor.getString(1));
            map.put("desc", cursor.getString(2));
            map.put("d1", cursor.getString(3));
            map.put("d2", cursor.getString(4));
            map.put("t1", cursor.getString(5));
            map.put("t2", cursor.getString(6)); 
            map.put("receiver", cursor.getString(7));                                                                                                           

            wordList.add(map);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }cursor.close();
    database.close();


    return wordList;
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain when do you call the getSentTask method? Is it called right after 'inserttask'? Inside an AsyncTask?

Comment: I have around 3 activities. i have created an instance of the databasehandler in each activity.In my addtask activity i have  a listview and a button. In listview i want the data from the database using the getTaskSent method. The button goes to another activity where i insert data to the database using inserttask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Context` you pass to your `Databasehandler` constructor is `null`.

Comment: To get help fixing that, please post code where you initialize your databasehandler. Also, generally you should post full exception stacktrace and not just one line of it, though in this case it's easy to figure out since this issue is asked here multiple times each week.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Migol: It does to the degree of detail available in the question. Please be careful in VLQ reviews, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good and should not cause the exception.

The exception occures in fact when an activity (or task) tries to access database for writing while it is already open for writing elsewhere (an other activity, class, ...etc.).

I suggest you implement the solution described here: https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/dmytrodanylyk/blob/gh-pages/articles/Concurrent%20Database%20Access.md .

It is based on two things: 
SQLite does not always return a readable database when you call getReadableDatabase but may return a writable database, and using one SQLiteOpenHelper single instance everywhere (singleton) and one single instance of SQLiteDatabase from the Open Helper singleton.

The solution may look overkill but it is a best practice when using SQLite: your app gets more scalable (queries are fast) and thread safe (prevent queries collisions).

I hope this helps and I'm remain availabel for any questions :).

Comment: It doesn't help. Can you please suggest some other solution for this error?

Comment: Hi, sure! I'll need some more ifnormation if you don't mind :). I'll need to understand the whole process: if my understanding is good you run the app and it shows a list of tasks with a button. Then you select one (or more?) tasks and hit the button. Then you see a screen with a new activity that calls inserttask. What happens next? I'll also need to know if the exception occures from the first time you use the add button or after after a successful use? The complete stack trace may also help me see more.

Comment: hey.. I got the solution for the error. Actually I was passing a null context to the database constructor.

Comment: @laalto you must be a genius :D.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RetriveMyApplicationContext extends Application {

   /*Don't forget to mention RetriveMyApplicationContext Class in Manifests    File otherwise it will throw NullPointer Exception
    <application
    android:name=".volley.RetriveMyApplicationContext"*/


    private static RetriveMyApplicationContext mRetriveMyApplicationContext;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mRetriveMyApplicationContext = this;
}

      public static RetriveMyApplicationContext getInstance() {

         return mRetriveMyApplicationContext;
   }

       public static Context getAppContext() {

       return mRetriveMyApplicationContext.getApplicationContext();
}
}
```

*First Create The Above Class and use the above class to Pass the Context*
*eg;*

```
DatabaseHandler d = new DatabaseHandler(RetriveMyApplicationContext.getAppContext());
```

**Finally Add into Manifest File**

```
<application
    android:name="<Your Package Name>.RetriveMyApplicationContext"
    ........


       > 
   <activity .....
```