# Android NullPointerException and GetDatabaseLocked

Tags: java, android, sqlite, singleton, database-locking

Im trying to store a particular columns data in a method and call that method in another classes String [] where a spinner will access that array to display the columns rows for the user to select which will then get stored in another database.

Im getting nulpointerexception and when I try and open() the database the database gets locked. Sorry for sounding like a complete amateur, relatively new to android. Thank you in advance for any help.

**Here is my code when I call getInstance() and getCPnames() in my main class**

```
    String[] carParks = CarParkDb.getInstance().getCpnames();
```

**Here is my code for the database:**

```
package com.example.parkangel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class CarParkDb {


    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_CPNAME = "cpname";
    public static final String KEY_COST = "cost";


    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CPDB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "CPTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private CPDbHelper cpdbHelper;

    private Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
    private static CarParkDb instance;


    private static class CPDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public CPDbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }



@Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    KEY_CPNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_COST + " TEXTNOT NULL);");

            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values('1','LearningResource Center','2');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values ('2','ParkandRide','1');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values ('3','deHavilland Campus','2');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values('4','MultiStorey Building','2');");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + DATABASE_TABLE + " Values('5','Reception','2');");

        }

        public void onOpen(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onOpen(db);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

        public CarParkDb (final Context c)
        {
            this.cpdbHelper= new CPDbHelper(c);
            establishDb();
            //ourContext = c;
}
        public void establishDb()
        {
            if (this.ourDatabase == null)
            {
                this.ourDatabase = this.cpdbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            }

        }

        public CarParkDb() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        public CarParkDb open() throws SQLException
        {
            System.out.println ("running open");
            cpdbHelper = new CPDbHelper(ourContext);
            ourDatabase = cpdbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        public void close()
        {
            ourDatabase.close();
        }

        /*public long createEntry(String cpname, String cost){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_CPNAME, cpname);
            cv.put(KEY_COST, cost);
            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
        }*/

        public String getData() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //open();
            String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_ID, KEY_CPNAME, KEY_COST};
            Cursor  c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,null,null, null, null);
            String result = " ";

            int iRow = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ID);
            int iCpname = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_CPNAME);
            int iCost = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_COST);

            for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
                result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " +c.getString(iCpname) + " " + c.getString(iCost) + " " + "\n";
                c.close();
                ourDatabase.close();
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static CarParkDb getInstance()
        {
            synchronized(CarParkDb.class)
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new CarParkDb();
            }   
            return instance;
        }
        }

    public String[] getCpnames()
        {
            //open();
            if (ourDatabase == null) System.out.println ("is null");
            Cursor c = null;

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            ourDatabase = cpdbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            //SQLiteDatabase db = cpdbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "SELECT " + KEY_CPNAME + " FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;



            {
            c = this.ourDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
            int iCpname = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_CPNAME);
            if (c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                    list.add(c.getString(iCpname));;
                    }           
                    while (c.moveToNext());
                }
                if (c != null && !c.isClosed())
                {
                c.close();
                ourDatabase.close();
                }
                return list.toArray(new String[]{});
            }
        }

} 

**LogCat**

    03-12 01:32:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(4176): Caused by:java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-12 01:32:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(4176):     

    at com.example.parkangel.CarParkDb.getCpnames(CarParkDb.java:191)
    03-12 01:32:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(4176):     

    at com.example.parkangel.BookTicket.<init>(BookTicket.java:22)
    03-12 01:32:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(4176):     

    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    03-12 01:32:39.759: E/AndroidRuntime(4176):     

    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
```

Comment: [How can i fix SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked error while trying to access a SQLite database in android?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985696/how-can-i-fix-sqliteopenhelper-getdatabaselocked-error-while-trying-to-access-a/30932457#30932457

*Solution  Is in the above Stackoverflow Link.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985696/how-can-i-fix-sqliteopenhelper-getdatabaselocked-error-while-trying-to-access-a/30932457#30932457

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your `getInstance()` code with this:

```
public static CarParkDb getInstance(Context c) // <-- added context as parameter
{
    synchronized(CarParkDb.class)
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new CarParkDb(c); // <-- used context in constructor
        }   
        return instance;
    }
}
```

The problem seems to be that you're using a constructor (for `CarParkDb`) that does nothing. You have another constructor that takes a `Context` as parameter and initializes some of the objects that you're using later.

Comment: Hi thank you for your speedy answer. I had to also change 

    String[] carParks=CarParkDb.getInstance().getCpnames();

to

    String[] carParks=CarParkDb.getInstance(null).getCpnames();

I get the following messages in LogCat:

03-12 02:13:58.269: E/AndroidRuntime(5957): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

03-12 02:13:58.269: E/AndroidRuntime(5957):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)

03-12 02:13:58.269: E/AndroidRuntime(5957):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)

Comment: You should not pass `null` to the `getInstance()` function, you should pass a Context object, if you're calling it from an Activity you can use `this` instead of `null`.

Comment: Im calling it from the database class so not quite sure what to put in there. Also Ive tried a lot of things to stop the database from getting locked but it seems every little change either causes nullpointerexception or database being locked. Just going in circles :/

Answer (score 2):

The database doesn't get locked. The "locked" thinkg is just a NPE in a method called `getDatabaseLocked()` and it's caused by a `null` `Context` passed to `SQLiteOpenHelper` in constructor that manifests itself with `getWritableDatabase()` or `getReadableDatabase()`.

To fix the NPE in `getDatabaseLocked()`, make sure `ourContext` in `open()` is not `null`. As of now, you've never initialized `ourContext` and it's always `null`. Uncomment the `//ourContext = c;` in constructor and move it above the `establishDb()`, remove the other no-argument constructor and pass in a `Context` for example as suggested by Merlevede.

The NPE stacktrace in your question is when you call `getCpNames()` with `open()` commented out and are trying to call a method on a `null` `ourDatabase` object reference. Uncomment the `open()` there once it's fixed. The stacktrace also says you're trying to call `getCpNames()` in object initialization phase e.g. when initializing a member variable. That might be too early, for example an activity cannot be used as a `Context` until `onCreate()`.

Some other things in your code you'd hit next:

- in `onCreate()`: `+ KEY_COST + " TEXTNOT NULL)` - add space between `TEXT` and `NOT`
- in `getData()`: you're closing the cursor and database in the loop where you're accessing the cursor. Do it after the loop. The code shouldn't compile as you're not returning anything from a non-void function in case `moveToFirst()` returns false.

Comment: Hi thank you for you answer. Unfortunately it has not worked for me.
I get the following error along with the usual database locked error:

03-12 12:31:41.879: E/AndroidRuntime(3110):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:256)